# Stopping/starting an application pool and site on a server

Tags: cmd, server, web, application-pool

I would like to write a script and run it from my local PC to stop and start an application pool and site that exists on a server.

Value of App Pool and Site - Test
Value of server - SERVER1

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

Run Command Prompt with Administrative rights, and type the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:"MYAPPPOOLNAME"
```

or use the `stop` command. You could save this in a batch file, but it must be executed with higher privileges.

For the application pool on a remote server, you could use [PsExec](https://serverfault.com/questions/223496/recycle-remote-iis-app-pool-from-the-command-line):

```
Psexec \\{Computer Name of ISS7 Server} C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool my-app-pool
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Maybe I should have been clearer.

The command is fine locally or on the server, but I want to run the command from my PC, therefore the command needs to mention the server name.